# iOS Safari - Customize HTML5 Mobile Media Capture UI

Tags: ios, html, safari, capture, getusermedia

I've been reading about invoking a mobile device's camera and allowing the user to take a picture in HTML5, and I found I can do it using an input element like so:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

I also read about the `getUserMedia()` API, but it doesn't seem as though it's supported by Safari very well.

I want to customize the UI that is visible while the user is taking a screenshot. A couple examples of the customization I'd like to perform are overlaying text on the screen and drawing rectangles to show what portion of the screen will be captured. This is already done in native apps, but is it possible in the web?

If not, is there any sort of workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible on the web (yet).

HTML Media Capture (the code you used) relies on the OS & browser for the camera & library apps.

Also, the code you used is deprecated, here's the correct one: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>` .

This (new) code will tell the browser 2 things:

1. `accept="image/*"` → you want to take a picture (not a video or audio)
2. `capture` → only get a picture from the camera (not from the library, works only on Android)

See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for more info.